# py2exe, paramiko error, ImportError

Tags: python, py2exe

I am programming server-client App using python.

I need to run client side App on windows so I tried to compile script to exe with py2exe.

In head of client app:

```
import paramiko
import threading
import subprocess
```

so in setup I import paramiko

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, os, paramiko
setup(console=['client.py'])
```

when I tried to run compiled file:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "client.py", line 3, in
>      File "paramiko__init__.pyc", line 30, in
>
> File "paramiko\transport.pyc", line 32, in 
>       s♥   File "cryptography\hazmat\backends__init__.pyc", line 7, in
>
> File "pkg_resources__init__.pyc", line 68, in 
>       ☻☺t   File "pkg_resources\extern__init__.pyc", line 60, in load_module
>
> ImportError: The 'packaging' package is required; normally this is
>   bundled with this package so if you get this warning, consult the
>   packager of your distribution.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Formatting ? I can hardly understand what's going on

Answer (score 0):

Try running `pip install packaging` and recompiling.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "paramiko\__init__.pyc", line 30, in <module>
  File "paramiko\transport.pyc", line 32, in <module>
  File "cryptography\hazmat\backends\__init__.pyc", line 7, in <module>
  File "pkg_resources\__init__.pyc", line 68, in <module>
  File "pkg_resources\extern\__init__.pyc", line 60, in load_module
ImportError: The 'packaging' package is required; normally this is bundled with
this package so if you get this warning, consult the packager of your distributi
on.

Comment: Did it install the packaging package successfully?